# Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I hope someone can help me solve this error.
This is my buil.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.addimando.esell"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The initial problem was:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
```

And to solve this I added some exclusions in the gradle.
The last working project was without the facebook plugin to log in my app.
I really need this type of login and I can't give it up.

Comment: I think I solved this error with this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes